# C# : Resetting DataGridView for new DataTable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource

Ok so I'm trying to make a simple SQL CE Viewer application just to view my local databases for another application, I have it setup so that I can select what database I want to open and then it automatically populates a combo box with all of the tables in the database.  When I select a table it populates a DataGridView with the records in the table.

My problem is switching between tables.  I can't seem to get the DataGridView to remove everything from the previous table and re-populate the DataGridView with the new table information.  Of course each table has different columns and rows and such.

I've googled and searched on here and every suggestion I find doesn't seem to work.  It populates the DataGridView with the first table just fine, but when I select another it basically adds the columns and rows into whatever was there....

How can I get the DataGridView to completely clear for new data?

And please don't tell me to use dataGridView1.DataSource = null;  tried that, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I checked it in one of my programs and just changing DataSource property is working fine. I didn't have to use datagridview.Refresh(). Maybe it depends on the kind of DataSource, which you are using to set datagridview data?

Comment: `conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = " + fixFilePath);
using (conn)
{
conn.Open();
command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, conn);

daDataGridView = new SqlCeDataAdapter(command);
daDataGridView.Fill(dtDataGridView);
bsDataGridView.DataSource = dtDataGridView;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bsDataGridView;
}`

Comment: I am not sure, but your problem may occure because you are not clearing up datatable before setting new table to it. Multiple Fill method on single DataTable most probably is appending new rows to existing ones. If you haven't tried, you can check this out. As I said, I am not 100% sure and can't check this out on my own now. You can also try using DataSet and then add new selected tables as DataTables to it.

Comment: I got it working....  Just needed to move the DataTable = new DT and BindingSource = new BS and add a dataGridView.Refresh() into the top of the dataGridSetup() method just before it sets up the dataGridView.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Write this line after you have done populating the `DataSource` with the new data

```
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

You don't need to clear the `DataGridView` directly. Its always handled by modifying the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing else in the form, you can simply call `InitializeComponent()` again. But I think @Josh is right.